# Elliptic equations and Fredholms alternative in the non-compact case

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, smooth-manifolds, elliptic-pde

Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold and $E$ be a finite-rank vector bundle over $M$ equipped with a bundle metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E^{\ast}\otimes E^{\ast})$, i.e. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a positive-definite inner product on each fibre. This induces an inner product on the level of (compactly-supported) sections via
$$(\cdot,\cdot):=\int_{M}\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\,\mathrm{vol}_{g}.$$

Now, if $M$ is compact and $L:\Gamma^{\infty}(E)\to\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ a formally self-adjoint elliptic operator, then the famous Fredholm alternatives states that the elliptic equation
$$Lu=f$$
for some source $f\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ has a smooth solution $u\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ if and only if $(f,g)=0$ for all $g\in\ker(L)$.

> If $M$ is non-compact, is there a similar statement, i.e. if $f\in\Gamma^{\infty}_{c}(E)$ does there exists a compactly-supported smooth solution $u\in\Gamma^{\infty}_{c}(E)$ if and only if $f$ is orthogonal to every element in $\ker(L\vert_{\Gamma^{\infty}_{c}})$?

Comment: This is tricky. There are few results in the noncompact case since noncompactness  can manifest itself in so many ways. An  old result that covers a special case of non compactness is due to Lockhard and McOwen. http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_1985_4_12_3_409_0/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out! Also, I just realized, my precise formulation also makes not a lot of sense since $\mathrm{ker}(L\vert_{c})$ is probably empty for many operators by unique continuation

Comment: More precisly, the example I am interested most, is whether there are compactly supported smooth solutions of the equation $\Delta_g f=\delta\omega$ for some compactly supported smooth 1 form omega.

Comment: @G.Blaickner  in view of your last comment then this might be relevant: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442169/poisson-equation-on-manifolds

Comment: @Overflowian actually, my question is motivated from this post. Rbega2 claimed that a necessaty condition for compactly supported solutions is that the source is orthogonal to the kernel of L. I wanted to know if it is also sufficient. Since in this case my Poisson equation can be solved, as $\delta\omega$ is clearly orthogonal to harmonic L^2 functions, since harmonic L^2 functions are closed.

Comment: @G.Blaickner Well in the setting of manifolds with cylindrical ends, under certain conditions, if the source is L^2-orthogonal to the kernel of the formal adjoint of the operator then there is a solution which decays exponentially over the ends but  this doesn't mean that the solution will be compactly supported.